# is it possible to use earths magnetic field as a energy source while in space?

Tags: orbital-mechanics

While in space or on the moon is it possible to use earth existing magnetic field to generate electricity?

Comment: @DrSheldon A ring around the earth is different than what is proposed here. There may be a duplicate question in this site, but I don't think that is the right choice; those answers do not answer this question. Closing as duplicate is not something we do because the questions are similar, it has to be based on the answers there answering this question properly, and I don't think your selection meets that criterion.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, sort of.

The most basic form of electrical generator consists of a wire moving through an electrical field.  In space, this would take the form of an "[electrodynamic tether](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrodynamic_tether)": a wire extended outwards from a spacecraft.

But energy needs to come from somewhere, and with an electrodynamic tether, the energy comes from the spacecraft's orbital motion.  This slows the spacecraft down and will eventually cause it to re-enter.  A more common proposal for using an electrodynamic tether is to run it in reverse: use a solar panel to run an electric current through the tether, causing it to act as an electric motor.  This would let the spacecraft adjust its orbit without needing to use fuel.